# Code coverage results are not available in TeamCity

Tags: msbuild-4.0, partcover, teamcity-7.1

I am using TeamCity 7.1 with MsBuild build step running the following task:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Target Name="BuildTrunk" DependsOnTargets="Compile;Test" />
  <Target Name="Compile">
    <MSBuild Projects="Project.sln" Targets="Rebuild" Properties="Configuration=DEBUG" />
  </Target>
  <Target Name="Test">
    <NUnitTeamCity Assemblies="@(TestAssemblies)" NUnitVersion="NUnit-2.5.10" />
  </Target>
  <ItemGroup>
    <TestAssemblies Include="Project.Tests\bin\Debug\Project.Tests.dll" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

And I configured PartCover for this step (set path to PartCover 4.0.2 libraries, used proper XSLT files, also copied just in case PartCover.dll and renamed it to PartCover.CorDriver.dll), however once tests are executed code coverage results are not available and "Code Coverage" tab is not displayed in TeamCity. What is wrong with this configuration?

Comment: What .NET version are you using (2,4,4.5)?

Comment: I am afraid this is one for the [teamcity people](http://blog.jetbrains.com/teamcity/tag/partcover/) - partcover should work for .NET 4.
Personally I'd use [OpenCover](http://scubamunki.blogspot.com.au/2011/10/adding-opencover-to-teamcity.html) as that is more flexible and is being actively supported and developed it also has 32 and 64 bit support whereas PartCover only works for 32 bit applications (which may be your problem, it's hard to tell)

Comment: Thanks, I temporary switched to JetBrains dotCover.